# How do I check if a Guid value is inside a LIST of Structures?

Tags: linq, list, struct

How do I check if a Guid value is inside a LIST of Structures?

```
public struct Info
{
   public Guid EntityTypeID;
   public String Name;
}


List<Info> InfoList = <function which populates the list of Struct>
...

var values = ctx.EntityValues.Where(v => v.EntityID == e.ID
                               && InfoList.Contains(v.EntityTypeItemID)).ToList(); <=== problem here!
                //or something like: InfoList[i].EntityTypeID.Contains(v.EntityTypeItemID)).ToList();
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: What is `e`? And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: And what's the problem you speak of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for `Any`:

```
... InfoList.Any(x => x.EntityTypeID == v.EntityTypeItemID)
```

You can't use `Contains`, because you're looking for something which matches *part* of the item.

(I'd also strongly discourage using public fields and indeed having mutable structures at all, but that's a different matter.)

Another option would be to create a list of the GUIDs you're interested in:

```
var guids = InfoList.Select(x => x.EntityTypeID).ToList();
```

Then you can use:

```
... guids.Contains(v.EntityTypeItemID)
```

That may work where the previous code didn't, as it moves the extraction of the type ID out of the main query.

Comment: thanks for the response but I got the error:
"Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: @Max: So is this LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? Something else? And have you isolated the problem to *just this* part? I've got another idea - I'll edit it in.

Comment: Jon I was trying to avoid that extra step. That is why I was trying to find a way where I could verify if a specific GUID is inside my List or Structures....so I will take the approach you suggested for now; sometimes we spend too much time in these little things :-)... thank you again and take care!